# Android emulator 3.0 kernel

Tags: android, linux, kernel, arm, emulation

Does anyone know what config file I should use when compiling the linux 3.0 kernel in order to make it work with the Android Emulator from the sdk (4.0 or any other verion)?

Something like this perhaps?:

```
./emulator-arm -avd default-v7 -shell -kernel /path/to/default/kernel/linux/arch/arm/boot/zImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Upstream (mainline, vanilla) Linux Kernel 3.0 can't boot Android userspace. You need to patch it with Android support. Kernel 3.3 is closer, but still missing a piece: https://lwn.net/Articles/472984/

Why don't you use AOSP kernel source? http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html